# Filtering a backbone collection with multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I've written a short piece of code to get myself familiar with backbone.js. I'm filtering 100 results from the Twitter API. Once those are in, I use a time picker and a hash tag selector to filter my results. I want the filter to work in the following manner:

1. Pick a time range, get a filtered collection and a filtered set of hash tags in the selector tag. Pick a hash tag, filter the SAME RESULTS within that time range.
2. Pick a hash tag, get a filtered collection. Select a date and filter the same results gotten with the originally chosen hashtag.
3. Dont lose the original collection.

Here's my code:

```
            "use strict";
    // Define the model
    var Tweet = Backbone.Model.extend({});

    // Define the collection
    var Tweets = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        initialize : function(options) {
            if (options !== undefined) {
                if (options.location !== undefined) {
                    this.location = options.location;
                    // console.log(location);
                }
            }
        },

        model : Tweet,
        parse : function(response) {
            var data = response.results;
            $(data).each(
                    function() {
                        var timezoneOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / -60;
                        // var offset = Date.getTimezoneOffset(today.getTimezone(),
                        // today.hasDaylightSavingTime());
                        // console.log(timezoneOffset);
                        var dateTime = Date.parse(this.created_at).addHours(
                                timezoneOffset).toString(
                                "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy, h:mm:ss tt");
                        this.created_at = dateTime;
                        this.text = twttr.txt.autoLink(this.text);
                        this.from_user = twttr.txt.autoLink("@" + this.from_user);
                        // console.log("user: ", this.from_user);
                    });
            // console.log('\nformatted data: ', data);
            return data;
        },

        // Overwrite the sync method to pass over the Same Origin Policy
        sync : function(method, model, options) {
            // console.log(options);
            var self = this;

            var params = {
                url : 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=' + self.location
                        + '&rpp=100&lang=all&include_entities=true',
                type : 'GET',
                dataType : 'jsonp',
                processData : false
            };

            options = _.extend(options, params);

            return $.ajax(options);
        },

        showhide : function(toDate, fromDate) {
            // console.log(toDate,"\n", fromDate,"\n", this.models);
            var results;

            //if(toDate !== undefined && fromDate !== undefined){
                results = this.filter(function(tweet) {

                    var tweetDate = Date.parse(tweet.attributes.created_at);
                    if (tweetDate.between(fromDate, toDate)) {
                        //console.log("valid ", tweet);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            //}
            return results;
            console.log("Date Filtered Results: ", results);
        },

        selectShowHide : function(selectedHashTag){
            var results;
            if(selectedHashTag !== 'all'){
                results = this.filter(function(tweet){
                    var hashtag = tweet.attributes.entities.hashtags;
                    //console.log("hashtag array: ", hashtag);
                    var matchingHashTag = "";
                    $(hashtag).each(function(){
                        if(this.text == selectedHashTag){
                            return matchingHashTag = true;
                        }
                    });
                    return matchingHashTag;
                });
            }
            else{
                results = this.filter(function(tweet){
                    return true;
                });
            }
            return results;
            console.log("Date Filtered Results: ", results);
        }
    });

    // Define the Master View
    var MasterView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize : function() {
            // console.log("Master View Initialized");
        },
        events : {
            "click #buttonSubmit" : "doSearch",
        },
        doSearch : function() {
            // console.log(this);
            var $self = this.$el;
            // THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT!!! DEFINE A TOP VIEW LEVEL COLLECTION FOR YOUR
            // VIEWS TO WORK ON
            // IF YOU WISH TO DO FRONT END FILTERING ON YOUR RESULTS!!!
            var TweetResults = new Tweets({
                location : $self.find('#textLocation').val()
            });

            TweetResults.fetch({
                success : function(collection, resp) {
                    var dateView = new DateView({
                        el : $('#date'),
                        collection : collection
                    });

                    var selectView = new SelectView({
                        el: $('#hashTag'),
                        collection: collection
                    });

                    var resultsView = new ResultsView({
                        el : $('#display'),
                        collection : collection
                    });

                    var resetView = new ResetView({
                        el: $("#reset"),
                        collection : collection
                    });
                }
            });

        }
    });

    // Define the reset View
    var ResetView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function(options){
            this.collection = options.collection;
            this.render();
        },
        render: function(){
            this.$el.html("");
            var self = this;
            $.ajax({
                url : '../templates/ResetTemplate.html',
                cache : false,
                success : function(data) {
                    templateLoader(data, self);
                }
            });
        },
        events:{
            "click #buttonReset": "collectionReset"
        },
        collectionReset: function(){
            var dateView = new DateView({
                el : $('#date'),
                collection : this.collection
            });

            var resultsView = new ResultsView({
                el : $('#display'),
                collection : this.collection
            });

            var selectView = new SelectView({
                el: $('#hashTag'),
                collection: this.collection
            });
        }
    });

    // Define the date View
    var DateView = Backbone.View
            .extend({
                initialize : function(options) {
                    // console.log('Date View Initialized');
                    this.collection = options.collection;
                    this.render();
                },
                render : function() {
                    this.$el.html("");
                    var self = this;
                    $.ajax({
                        url : '../templates/DateTemplate.html',
                        cache : false,
                        success : function(data) {
                            templateLoader(data, self);
                            datePicker(self, "#textFrom");
                            datePicker(self, "#textTo");
                        }
                    });
                },
                events : {
                    "click #buttonFilter" : "showHide"
                },
                // filter the results
                showHide : function() {
                    var fromDate = "";
                    var toDate = "";

                    if ($('#textFrom').val() === "") {
                        alert("Please Enter a 'From' Date");
                    } else {
                        fromDate = Date.parse($('#textFrom').val());
                    }

                    if ($('#textTo').val() === "") {
                        alert("Please Enter a 'To' Date");
                    } else {
                        toDate = Date.parse($('#textTo').val());
                    }
                    if (toDate && fromDate && fromDate.isBefore(toDate)) {

                        var filteredCollection = new Tweets(this.collection
                                .showhide(toDate, fromDate));

                        //console.log("filtered results: ", filteredCollection);

                        var filteredResultsView = new ResultsView({
                            el : $('#display'),
                            collection : filteredCollection
                        });

                        /*var filteredSelectView = new SelectView({
                            el : $('#hashTag'),
                            collection : filteredCollection
                        });*/
                    } else {
                        alert("Please check if your 'From' date comes before your 'To' date!");
                    }
                }
            });

    //Define the select View
    var SelectView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize : function(options) {
            // create a collection
            this.collection = options.collection;
            //console.log('select collection: ', this.collection);
            this.render();
        },
        render : function() {
            this.$el.html("");
            var self = this;
            $.ajax({
                url : '../templates/HashTagSelectionTemplate.html',
                cache : true,
                success : function(data) {
                    templateLoader(data, self);
                }
            });
        },
        events:{
            "change #selectHashTag" : "selectShowHide" 
        },
        selectShowHide: function()
        {
            var selected = $("#selectHashTag").find("option:selected").val();
            console.log("selected option: ", selected);

            var filteredCollection = new Tweets(this.collection
                    .selectShowHide(selected));

            var filteredResultsView = new ResultsView({
                el : $('#display'),
                collection : filteredCollection
            });

            /*var filteredDateView = new DateView({
                el : $('#date'),
                collection : filteredCollection
            });*/
        }
    });

    // Define the results View
    var ResultsView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize : function(options) {
            // console.log(options);
            // create a collection
            this.collection = options.collection;

            this.render();
        },
        render : function() {
            this.$el.html("");
            var self = this;
            $.ajax({
                url : '../templates/TweetsTemplate.html',
                cache : false,
                success : function(data) {
                    templateLoader(data, self);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // function to handle template loading
    function templateLoader(data, self) {
        var source = data;
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        var html = template(self.collection);
        self.$el.html(html);
    }

    // function to attach the datepicker to the supplied element
    function datePicker(self, elementId) {
        self.$el.find(elementId).datetimepicker({
            dateFormat : "DD, dd MM yy",
            ampm : true
        });
    }

    var app = new MasterView({
        el : $('#fieldsetForm')
    });
```

Am I on the right track? Should I be using another way? Am I in danger of memory leaks?

Comment: It basically looks alright, and with the little data you process (100 tweets) you don't have to worry about memory leaks. There are some things that could be improved, but these kinds of things should be discussed at codereview: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks. Basically, I'm using the Reset View to restore all other views with the original collection if it gets lost during filtering. Can I incorporate this logic into the date and select filtering functions themselves? I've also posted this on codereview.stackexchange.com at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13454/filtering-a-backbone-collection-with-multiple-parameters